# zsh scp completion of remote files doesn't work when running SSHHelper

Tags: ssh, rsync

Running [SSHelper](https://arachnoid.com/android/SSHelper/) is a great way to access files on your phone. But completion of remote files (`scp` and `rsync`) using zsh doesn't work though. While using `sshfs` is a workaround but sometimes you just want to pull/push a quick file, it's not really satisfying.

Where lies the culprit, and how can I get file completion working properly via `zsh`?

Answer (score 2):

The culprit is android's crippled `ls` command. Zsh's completion run `ls -d1FL` which `/system/bin/ls` doesn't understand.

A way to fix this is to edit `/data/data/com.arachnoid.sshelper/home/.ssh/environment` such that `/data/user/0/com.arachnoid.sshelper/bin` is the first entry in `PATH`. (SSHelper ships with a more complete `ls`)

Note that SSHelper might rewrite this file on updates?

Comment: Nice detail, thanks! Speaking of updates: if you use F-Droid, you can find the app [in my repo](https://apt.izzysoft.de/fdroid/index/apk/com.arachnoid.sshelper) (it uses the devs signature, so you can simply update what you got from there). And besides, as you've identified the culprit as the pre-installed `ls` command: was that the "stock" one, or would the `ls` provided by Busybox have the same limitation?

Comment: `busybox ls` is sufficient I think. Ie. `busybox ls` supports at least some of the flags that the system doesn't.